# Keyboard constantly closes with each typed on input child

Tags: typescript, react-native

Every time I type something it closes the keyboard I've tried using `onChangeText` and `onChange` but nothing has changed

Parent component

```
const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('');

function handleSearchTextChange(e: NativeSyntheticEvent<TextInputChangeEventData>) {
  setSearchText(e.nativeEvent.text);
}

<PageHeader
   hasSearch={true}
   isLogout={true}
   searchTextInput={searchText}
   onSearchTextChange={handleSearchTextChange}
/>
```

child component

```
        <TextInput
          style={{width: 250}}
          autoCorrect={true}
          placeholder="Pesquisar..."
          value={searchTextInput}
          onChange={onSearchTextChange}
        />
```

Comment: Can you create an expo snack with a reproducible example?

Comment: I've dealt with this problem a lot and basically it happens whenever you are inadvertently creating a new instance of `TextInput` on each change.  Like if your TextInput child was a variable that you returned from a function or assigned outside of `render`.  I can't say more specifically than that without seeing the full code.